# Is $\forall r \in \mathbb{R}, r^3 \notin \mathbb{Q} \implies r \notin \mathbb{Q}$ true?

Tags: proof-verification, rational-numbers

> Is $\forall r \in \mathbb{R}, r^3 \notin \mathbb{Q} \implies r \notin \mathbb{Q}$ true?

True

Contrapositive;

$r = a/b \in \mathbb{Q}$ then $r^3 = a^3/b^3 \in \mathbb{Q}$

Correct?

Comment: It is bad practice to say everything with symbols. Try using words instead.

Answer (score 4):

your argument is correct! Contrapositive is the way to go.